# Buying advice for new road/race bike approx. £1000 for racing

Tags: racing, advice

I'm looking for a new bike for approx. £1000 with the intention to, by the end of the year, get into road racing.

I've had a Trek 1.5 (Tiagra groupset, alu frame) for about 7 years now and it's been great but it's a bit long in the tooth and having had a quick blast on some other bikes it's decidedly not very fast (even with fulcrum wheel upgrade, better tyres etc..) It's time for something new (also need to use the trek as a winter bike..)

I've been keen on getting a b'twin bike - namely the 720 AF, this is top of my list (ultegra groupset, decent 'race' geometry alu frame, good mavic wheelset).. however I'd like to see if there are any other bikes with a 105 groupset or above with a race geometry at the £1k-ish (or below!) mark.. but I don't even know where to look. I've found Wiggle's Eastway Emitter's OK but they don't get nearly as good writeup as the b'twin.

I'd like to avoid something with disc brakes as I'm guessing these won't be allowed in road races (and probably boost the price up a bit).

So far I've looked on chain reaction cycles, wiggle and evans cycles.. are there some other good places to look?

Really I'm just looking for ideas, good places to shop etc. My first bike I got I just went to the bike shop and asked 'what's good?' This time it's gotta be as good as it can get for the money..

Comment: Check out [ask] so that you can avoid having the question closed as a *product recommendation*. That said, what *kind* of road racing are you considering, and what do you mean by *race geometry*? And why Shi*mano?

Comment: Andy's right - this question has a good point "how to select a road bike" but needs to avoid specific models.  Shopping questions and comparison questions are of limited use, so they're classed as off topic for this site.  Consider using Edit to make your question less-shopping and more-method/approach.   And try to avoid regionalisation - "evans/CRC/wiggle" implies you're in the UK, but this site has a global audience.

Comment: Voted to close as answers are tending towards buying recommendations

Comment: Maybe my question should have been 'what website should I ask for buying advice on?' .. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to advise you on a specific bike, as everybody has it's own opinion. I've just bought a 2016 carbon ghost nivolet with discs and ultegra for 1400£, and here are a few things I considered prior to my purchase :

Value of a bike decreases a lot when bought new, I'd say around 30%. For that reason, buy a 2016 bike rather than a 2017. Chain Reaction still had some really neat offers on 'new' 2016 bikes not so long ago.

Some brands are a lot more value than others : Canyon, Rose, Ghost, Cube, BMC.
Look into those 'bang for the buck brands'. I valued german built, because carbon has to be well built.

Play with the exchange rate if you can.

That said, here is some things I noticed riding my bike :

> Carbon makes a lot of difference acceleration wise. I don't feel it's only because of weight.
>   Ultegra is definitely worth it. The shifting is incredibly smooth.
>   Disc brakes : Love them and would never look back, but these are indeed not allowed on races.

Comment: Yeah, I've been hunting around for 2016 stock but the problem is that all the bikes in my size have been long since snapped up. I *almost* got a killer bargain (b'twin 700 af) last night - (almost full) 105 groupset for £550 on a great frame.. but no, not in my size any more..grr.

Comment: @JohnHunt Did you check Alltricks as well ?

Comment: @Downvoter, care to comment ? I gave a general answer, that I feel is not time related.

Answer (score 0):

The Planet X EC-130 'Rivet Rider' was extremely well reviewed by Cycling Weekly last year and you can get them new from Planet X at around that kind of money.

Other than that, direct to consumer brands such as Canyon, Ribble and Rose may offer a few different options for around the 1k mark.

If you're happy to look used you can get a lot of bike for 1k, up to Dura-Ace/Super Record/Red groupsets on high end frames, just make sure you do your research and you should be fine.

Comment: Planet-X looks like a decent site, thanks. I'll also check out those other direct dealers.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.paulscycles.co.uk is always good for a punt.

And Planet X also do a build your own which can save you a few hundred.
http://www.planetx.co.uk/c/q/bikes/build-your-own

A Cannondale CAAD 12 is also an excellent racer's bike - some are on discount right now.